# Python garbled output when read TREC 2006 Spam Track Chinese Corpus

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm trying make a spam email filter, but when I read those file, it output garbled in terminal.

I download dataset from this address: https://plg.uwaterloo.ca/cgi-bin/cgiwrap/gvcormac/foo06

### Envoirment

MacOS 10.15
Python 3.6

### Dataset

### python script

this is my python script:

```py
# encoding=UTF-8
path = "/Users/jason/Documents/Note/Python_Data_Analysis_Fundamental/jieba_spam/trec06c/delay/"
s = []
f = open(path+"/index")
iter_f = iter(f)
str1 = ""
for line in iter_f:
    if(line[0] == 'H' or line[1] == 'P'):
        continue
    else:
        s.append(line[5:20])

for i in s:
    spam_path = path+i
    f = open(spam_path)
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

- Python2.7

```
...
Received: from sina.com ([61.48.9.188])

    by spam-gw.ccert.edu.cn (MIMEDefang) with ESMTP id j7VBFQ9v014498

    for <gong@ccert.edu.cn>; Sun, 4 Sep 2005 02:14:16 +0800 (CST)

Message-ID: <200508311915.j7VBFQ9v014498@spam-gw.ccert.edu.cn>

From: =?GB2312?B?t7bQob3j?= <yana@sina.com>

Subject: =?gb2312?B?tq+7rbPH0fvH68T6ss6806Oh?=

To: gong@ccert.edu.cn

Content-Type: text/plain;charset="GB2312"

Reply-To: yana@sina.com

Date: Sun, 4 Sep 2005 02:27:04 +0800

X-Priority: 3

X-Mailer: Microsoft Outlook Express 5.50.4133.2400

Ϊ?????й??Ŀ?ͨ?߽????ӵ?????,???????̨?ٶ???Ŀ?صؾٰ???һ????Ļ???»????--"???ӡ??????????⹫԰"ȫ??Ѳչ?.

??λ?????????Ӵ??????????Ȥ,?????ǿ??Էǳ????Ķȹ????????(ʮһ?ƽ??ܼ??Ժ??ʱ?????),????????Ļ???ҵ??˾?????????̻?.

?˴λ???????????̨??????????Ȩ????ʵҵ??չ???????ι?˾???Ҿ?Ӫ 

????˾????Э??.^C??Ϊ?????ܴ˴λ:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jason/Documents/Note/Python_Data_Analysis_Fundamental/jieba_spam/tf-idf.py", line 19, in <module>
    print(line)
KeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jason/.atom/packages/atom-python-run/lib/../cp/main.py", line 71, in <module>
    parser.call()
  File "/Users/jason/.atom/packages/atom-python-run/cp/cp/parse.py", line 130, in call
    self._exitCode = call(self._command)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 172, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1099, in wait
    pid, sts = _eintr_retry_call(os.waitpid, self.pid, 0)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 125, in _eintr_retry_call
    return func(*args)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

- Python3

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jason/Documents/Note/Python_Data_Analysis_Fundamental/jieba_spam/tf-idf.py", line 18, in <module>
    for line in f:
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd4 in position 256: invalid continuation byte

Process returned 1 (0x1)    execution time : 0.197 s
Close this window to continue...
```

Apply this change:

and will get

I'm trying to add some function like encode('gb2312) or decode('utf-8'), but they only can read the part of those file.

Any advice will be really help.

Comment: can you add a bare minimum sample text in a pastebin or something and link here?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem, the data set was GB2312, your need to write a shell script to convert those data to UTF-8.

This is my shell script in `/trec06/convert.sh`

```sh
for dir in `ls ~/Documents/Note/Python_Data_Analysis_Fundamental/jieba_spam/trec06c/data`; do
    for file in `ls ~/Documents/Note/Python_Data_Analysis_Fundamental/jieba_spam/trec06c/data/$dir`; do
    cd ~/Documents/Note/Python_Data_Analysis_Fundamental/jieba_spam/trec06c/data/$dir/    
    iconv -f GB2312 -t UTF-8 $file > $file'.txt'
    rm -rf $file
done
done
```

when execute this file, you will get .txt file, that can be recognized by python.